# change several images and text on hover and click

Tags: html, css, hover

I just had a question about how to change image and text on hover and click.
They are placed side by side and now I know how to swap them at the same time.
Now my follow-up question is: How can I make several of these Image&text to swap after one another?

Is it doable with css only? Or do i need to adddd some script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are asking is if you can swap them automatically, at a given interval of time, then the answer is **yes**, it is possible with CSS, using [**keyframe animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations) - you can animate the `opacity` property.

**UPDATE**: [**image gallery using keyframe animations**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3139170)

---

You can also do this when you have some kind of thumbnails or navigation buttons and in this case it's mostly the same technique I've used in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549483/1397351) for your previous question - a very basic (ahem, very basic means I did it in a couple of minutes a couple of weeks ago and then I was too lazy to come back to prettify) example of this kind of *gallery using thumbnails for navigation* you can see here http://dabblet.com/gist/3102051.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the number of times I want to swap the pair doesnt matter? I missed it and will look into it now. Thank you

Comment: It matters if you want the swapping to be done automatically (in order to compute the timing for each one). With the thumbnail/ nav buttons technique, no, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Okey is it with or without scripting?

Comment: It's all CSS3. Absolutely no JavaScript. It's all based on the `:checked` pseudo-class.

Comment: Great could you provide an example? I checked out your site. What knowledge in PHP do you have if i may ask?

Comment: Using thumbnails, it's at the end of my answer. Using keyframes or buttons, I can start making one now. PHP? Pretty basic, but enough to build a CMS from scratch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14103/discussion-between-user1535882-and-ana)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS :hover pseudo-class to change a background image (or change background position is using CSS sprites) on a hover event, but there is not a CSS-only way to do the same for a click event.  You would probably need to look at javascript for this

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using CSS only. check this blog post for details:
http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/. Can you also provide some sample code that will help understand how it can be done. Nevertheless, the link I mentioned above must be able to aid you.